# Samba configuration confusion

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, samba

I have deployed this docker container : https://github.com/dperson/samba

Using following config :

```
services:
  samba:
    image: dperson/samba
    environment:
      TZ: 'EST5EDT'
    ports:
      - "137:137/udp"
      - "138:138/udp"
      - "139:139/tcp"
      - "445:445/tcp"
    read_only: true
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /data:/data
    command: '-s "docker;/data/docker;yes;no;no;" -s "photo;/data/photo" -s "docker-dev;/data/docker-dev;yes;no;no;" -s "docker-prod;/data/docker-prod;yes;no;no;" -u "myuser;myuser" -p'
```

I am confused about the way Samba/Linux permissions are working :

I want to use the samba share from Windows and also Mac and have following questions :

1. Who should the owner be on the shares ?
2. Looking inside the docker container i see following config :

```
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options (perhaps too
# many!) most of which are not shown in this example
#
# For a step to step guide on installing, configuring and using samba, 
# read the Samba-HOWTO-Collection. This may be obtained from:
#  http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba-HOWTO-Collection.pdf
#
# Many working examples of smb.conf files can be found in the 
# Samba-Guide which is generated daily and can be downloaded from: 
#  http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba-Guide.pdf
#
# Any line which starts with a ; (semi-colon) or a # (hash) 
# is a comment and is ignored. In this example we will use a #
# for commentry and a ; for parts of the config file that you
# may wish to enable
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command "testparm"
# to check that you have not made any basic syntactic errors. 
#
#======================= Global Settings =====================================
[global]

# workgroup = NT-Domain-Name or Workgroup-Name, eg: MIDEARTH
   workgroup = MYGROUP

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
   server string = Samba Server

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller".
#
# Most people will want "standalone server" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

# This option is important for security. It allows you to restrict
# connections to machines which are on your local network. The
# following example restricts access to two C class networks and
# the "loopback" interface. For more examples of the syntax see
# the smb.conf man page
;   hosts allow = 192.168.1. 192.168.2. 127.

# Uncomment this if you want a guest account, you must add this to /etc/passwd
# otherwise the user "nobody" is used
;  guest account = pcguest

# this tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /dev/stdout

# Put a capping on the size of the log files (in Kb).
   max log size = 50

# Specifies the Kerberos or Active Directory realm the host is part of
;   realm = MY_REALM

# Backend to store user information in. New installations should 
# use either tdbsam or ldapsam. smbpasswd is available for backwards 
# compatibility. tdbsam requires no further configuration.
;   passdb backend = tdbsam

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting.
# Note: Consider carefully the location in the configuration file of
#       this line.  The included file is read at that point.
;   include = /usr/local/samba/lib/smb.conf.%m

# Configure Samba to use multiple interfaces
# If you have multiple network interfaces then you must list them
# here. See the man page for details.
;   interfaces = 192.168.12.2/24 192.168.13.2/24 

# Where to store roving profiles (only for Win95 and WinNT)
#        %L substitutes for this servers netbios name, %U is username
#        You must uncomment the [Profiles] share below
;   logon path = \\%L\Profiles\%U

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable it's WINS Server
;   wins support = yes

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
#   Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# WINS Proxy - Tells Samba to answer name resolution queries on
# behalf of a non WINS capable client, for this to work there must be
# at least one  WINS Server on the network. The default is NO.
;   wins proxy = yes

# DNS Proxy - tells Samba whether or not to try to resolve NetBIOS names
# via DNS nslookups. The default is NO.
   dns proxy = no 

# These scripts are used on a domain controller or stand-alone 
# machine to add or delete corresponding unix accounts
;  add user script = /usr/sbin/useradd %u
;  add group script = /usr/sbin/groupadd %g
;  add machine script = /usr/sbin/adduser -n -g machines -c Machine -d /dev/null -s /bin/false %u
;  delete user script = /usr/sbin/userdel %u
;  delete user from group script = /usr/sbin/deluser %u %g
;  delete group script = /usr/sbin/groupdel %g


   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
   create mask = 0664
   force create mode = 0664
   directory mask = 0775
   force directory mode = 0775
   force user = smbuser
   force group = smb
   follow symlinks = yes
   load printers = no
   printing = bsd
   printcap name = /dev/null
   disable spoolss = yes
   strict locking = no
   aio read size = 0
   aio write size = 0
   vfs objects = catia fruit recycle streams_xattr
   recycle:keeptree = yes
   recycle:maxsize = 0
   recycle:repository = .deleted
   recycle:versions = yes

   # Security
   client ipc max protocol = SMB3
   client ipc min protocol = SMB2_10
   client max protocol = SMB3
   client min protocol = SMB2_10
   server max protocol = SMB3
   server min protocol = SMB2_10

   # Time Machine
   fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
   fruit:time machine = yes
   fruit:veto_appledouble = no
   fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes

[docker]
   path = /data/docker
   browsable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = no
   veto files = /.apdisk/.DS_Store/.TemporaryItems/.Trashes/desktop.ini/ehthumbs.db/Network Trash Folder/Temporary Items/Thumbs.db/
   delete veto files = yes

[photo]
   path = /data/photo
   browsable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = yes
   veto files = /.apdisk/.DS_Store/.TemporaryItems/.Trashes/desktop.ini/ehthumbs.db/Network Trash Folder/Temporary Items/Thumbs.db/
   delete veto files = yes

[docker-dev]
   path = /data/docker-dev
   browsable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = no
   veto files = /.apdisk/.DS_Store/.TemporaryItems/.Trashes/desktop.ini/ehthumbs.db/Network Trash Folder/Temporary Items/Thumbs.db/
   delete veto files = yes

[docker-prod]
   path = /data/docker-prod
   browsable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = no
   veto files = /.apdisk/.DS_Store/.TemporaryItems/.Trashes/desktop.ini/ehthumbs.db/Network Trash Folder/Temporary Items/Thumbs.db/
   delete veto files = yes
```

How does the force user play with the user i have created when making the docker container ? I use the user to log in on the share from windows but when i copy files it uses the user specified in the force user. Is that ok ?

I have all weird problems when i copy files from windows and i then get errors, it's looking like something is not right on the permissions side.

Here is output from `less /etc/passwd`

```
smbuser:x:100:101:Samba User:/tmp:/sbin/nologin
myuser:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/home/myuser:/bin/ash
```

and here is the output from the shares using `ls -l`

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 systemd-timesync systemd-journal  2 May 11  2021 docker
drwxrwxr-x  4 systemd-timesync systemd-journal  5 Dec  8 14:37 docker-dev
drwxrwxr-x 46 systemd-timesync systemd-journal 47 May  7  2021 docker-prod
drwxrwxr-x  2 systemd-timesync systemd-journal  2 Apr 28  2021 photo
```

and the correspoding `less /etc/passwd` from the host machine where docker is running and the shares exists :

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:100:102:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-network:x:101:103:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-resolve:x:102:104:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
_apt:x:103:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
messagebus:x:104:111::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:105:65534::/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
_rpc:x:106:65534::/run/rpcbind:/usr/sbin/nologin
postfix:x:107:113::/var/spool/postfix:/usr/sbin/nologin
statd:x:108:65534::/var/lib/nfs:/usr/sbin/nologin
gluster:x:109:116::/var/lib/glusterd:/usr/sbin/nologin
ceph:x:64045:64045:Ceph storage service:/var/lib/ceph:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-coredump:x:999:999:systemd Core Dumper:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
myuser:x:1000:1000::/home/myuser:/bin/bash
dockeruser:x:3000:3000::/home/dockeruser:/bin/sh
ntp:x:110:117::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

I can see the `ID` is matched from the docker container to the share but i am not sure it's right and why i get the weird permissions problems. Maybe somebody can see something ?

/donnib